# What is the best way of deploying a neural network trained in tensorflow to torch C++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deployment, pytorch

I'm working on a project where I need to forward pass the network in C++ with PyTorch. The weights of the network need to be imported from a model trained in Tensorflow. I will write the C++ version of the network using Torch but I can not train the network in Torch because of some issues. Which methods can I use to do this?

Comment: When in doubt, the universal (though sometimes slow) persistent store is text.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

1. Convert TensorFlow model to ONNX/TensorRT/whatever using some converter. ONNX can be then converted to PyTorch (not sure about Torch), but you may find it unnecessary, as both ONNX and TensorRT are good for inference with their own runtimes. But in fact, you may face a lot of issues with conversion.
2. Reproduce model code with Torch, then copy TensorFlow tensors to their analogs in your code. You can see an example of such TF->PyTorch conversion in HuggingFace/Transformers code [1](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/convert_bert_original_tf_checkpoint_to_pytorch.py), [2](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/2d184cb553ee20943b03b253f44300e466357871/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L61). As you can see, it is quite tricky.